# How do I remove/unpublish my plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to remove my plugin from the plugin directory of wordpress because I dont want any new installs made with it. I can't find any solution from Google.

Comment: [Plugin Developer FAQ](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#closed-plugins) has the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of April 2020 you have the ability to close your own plugins without needing to contact them via email. Go to the ADVANCED VIEW link on sidebar of your plugin page and scroll down to the CLOSE THIS PLUGIN section. Read the warning. If that is acceptable to you, then click the button that says "I Understand..."

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, just did this myself.

Answer (score 3):

To remove a plugin from the WordPress repository, first delete the code via SVN. Then email `plugins@wordpress.org` using the email you registered with at wordpress.org (for the account that is the author of the plugin). They will delete it within a few days and email you back to confirm. They basically hide the plugin pages. The plugin slug remains blocked and your project can be resurrected if you can convince them to re-open it.